# Working with more than one project in VS Code

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, n-layer

I am developing .Net Core Web Application in Vs Code. The reason why I use Vs Code is, I am using Macbook Pro. Because of this, I preferred it. In my project I am creating N-Layer architecture. I have created different project in a folder, but not create "sln" project. I have some problems about build all the project same time, I was wondering should i create sln project before create other project ?

Comment: The order should not make a difference.  The child projects should be class projects and the main project should be a project that can be run from windows like a console project or Web application.

Comment: Why not use solution? What problems you are facing? Are you able to open all the projects in vs code by opening the main folder where all the projects are located inside sub folders?

Comment: You can download [Visual Studio for Mac](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/mac/) , it should be useful to you.